# How to handle >400 responses in api calls from redux app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, fetch, react-redux

Currently I using `fetch` to make api calls in my redux app.

I tried building a middleware api :-

```
export function api(endpoint,method,isAuth=false,body=null,multiPart=false,initToken=null)
{
  let promise = null
  let myHeaders = new Headers();
  if(!multiPart){
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  }


  if(isAuth){
    //if authorizations is needed adding header
      const accessToken = authentication.getAccessToken()
      myHeaders.append("Authorization",accessToken)
  }

  if(initToken){
    // in case of initToken adding to Authorization
    console.log("here"+initToken)
    myHeaders.append("Authorization",initToken)
  }

  let myInit = { method: method,headers: myHeaders};

  myInit['method'] = method
  myInit['headers'] = myHeaders

  if(body){
      myInit['body'] = body
  }


  let request = new Request(constants.BASE_URL+endpoint,myInit);
  promise = fetch(request)

  return promise
}
```

I inject the above in my thunk with extraArguments

```
export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store=createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(api),createLogger()),
      DevTools.instrument()
    ))
  return store
}
```

Following in my action which calls the api:-

```
export function fetchEmployeeInformation(){
  return (dispatch,getState,api) => {
        const endPoint = '//url'
        const  method = 'GET'
        const isAuth = true
        const promise = api(endPoint,method,isAuth)
        promise
        .then(response =>
          response.json().then(json => ({
            status:response.status ,
            json
          })
        ))
        .then(
          ({ status, json }) => {
            if( status >= 200 && status < 300) {
               //success
            }
            if (status >= 400 ) {
                //throw error
            }
          },
          err => {
            console.log("error"+err);
          }
        );
  }
}
```

So my question here is is there any package like [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) in angularjs which I can use with my react-redux app. I mean if status code is within range 200-299 it should make it as success or else throw an error.

With fetch I see it does not care much about the code and I have to specifically check whether the code range is above >400 and then throw error.

Is there any better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Library `axios` has similar flow as Angular $http including `requestInterceptor` and `responseInterceptor`.
Read More [docs](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#interceptors)

Comment: I just bumped into that library with bit of search. Let me try it once. Thanks :) . Do you use this for your projects ? @fazal

Comment: Yes, using on my current eCommerce project.

Comment: I had few questions regarding the API calls and handling things in my app? Can you please help me if you are free for sometime?

Comment: its becoming personal conversation. SO will not like that. Here is my fb: `https://www.facebook.com/FazalRasel`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [frisbee](https://github.com/crocodilejs/frisbee), which is a `fetch` API wrapper. Once you get the `response` object, you can check for an `err` or an `ok` boolean property.

Async example:

```
const api = new Frisbee({
   baseURI: 'https://yourapiurl.com'
})
const rs = await api.get(`url`)
if (rs.ok) {
  console.log('success')
} else {
  console.log('failure', rs.err)
}
```

Frisbee also works perfectly with node and React Native.